# PHP to get current page specific content

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to find out if it's possible & what code to use: to load the current page's contents and echo out a relative path to a specific page (c.html) that's w/in "#navbar a" using PHP or [PHP Simple Html DOM Parser.](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

My code so far:

```
<?php
$pg = 'c.html';
include_once '%resource(simple_html_dom.php)%';
/* $cpath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; Old version */  // Path to current pg from root
$cpath = "http://www.".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo var_dump($cpath).": Current Root Path"."<br />";  // "http://www.partiproductions.com/copyr/index.php" - Correct
$cfile = basename($cpath);
echo 'Current File: ' . $cfile . "<br />"; // "index.php" - Current pg, Correct

$html = file_get_html($cpath); // Getting Warning: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration & failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in.. & Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in...
foreach($html->find(sprintf('#navbar a[href=%s]', $pg)) as $path) {
  echo 'Path: ' . $path."<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: do a `print_r($_SERVER)` and see if there are any values there that you can use.

Comment: Try `$html = file_get_html('index.php');` and see if you get anything. If not, is `index.php` in the same directory as your script? If not, try getting `$cpath`.

Comment: Hi @cpilko Tried just index.php, but didn't work.  The index.php is the current page.  See comment to Wally below

Comment: I think I've gotten confused with what you're trying to do.

Are you trying to display a link to 'c.html' inside of your page? or are you trying to actually include the contents of 'c.html' inside of the index page?

Comment: @ Wally Lawless - Thanks so much for coming back - much appreciated.  Taking a step back - I ultimately want to bring in specific content from a specified pg 'c.html' into the current page(index.php in this example)  This was just the 1st step towards that, then initially thought I'd use jquery for bringing in content, BUT if we can do this all in php - that would be great !   I had developed a jquery way to bring in css file from c.html, but could never bring in js file & get it working. - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you have is with your call to file_get_html($cfile).

$cfile in your example would contain something like /copyr/index.php

When you pass this into file_get_html(), it is going to be looking for a directory /copyr in your server's root directory, and an index.php file inside of that.  Based on the warning that you've indicated, you don't actually have this folder structure at the root of your server.

What you actually need to do is include the full URL in front of the URI that you currently have, like this:

```
$cpath = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This will result in a path like this: http://www.yourserver.com/copyr/index.php which you should then work for file_get_html();

Comment: Ok Wally, I used  http://www. at beginning & it's now outputting current path as http:// www.partiproductions.com/copyr/index.php , but it's a string - would this cause a problem?  This php script is on the current page, as I didn't state that explicitly.  Getting:  Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in...

Comment: Using cpath getting: Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in..  AND  file_get_contents(http://www.partiproductions.com/copyr/index.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the updated information from the asker, I would follow a different approach.

Create a new file that contains only the content that you want to be shared across both files.  Then, in both of the files (or more later, if needed) use the include() function to inject the content from the new shared content file.

**index.php file:**

```
<?php
//Any require PHP code goes here
?>
<html>
    <body>
    <?php include('sharedfile.php');?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**/copyr/c.php file:**

```
<?php
//Any require PHP code goes here
?>
<html>
    <body>
    <?php include('../sharedfile.php');?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**sharedfile.php:**

```
// You need to close the PHP tag before echoing HTML content
?>
<p>
    This content is displayed via include() both on index.php and /copyr/c.php
</p>
<?php  // The PHP tag needs to be re-opened at the end of your shared file
```

The benefits here are that you can now use the sharedfile.php file content in any file you want across your site by following the same technique.  You also don't need to parse the DOM of the page to just strip out the content that you want to display across multiple pages, which can be slow and error-prone.

Comment: Lets stay w/ just index & c.html/php file for now.  In c file, I want to be able to target either #myid or .myclass and import that specific content into index.php.  The path to c.php needs to be found automatically.  In your approach, there was a file w/ only the content wanted, which I will not be able to do - must pull from a larger existing file (c.html/php) - Thanks